# How to include video into latex output

Tags: multimedia

The title says it all...

I couldn't be able to find a good tutorial or an example showing how to do it.

Do you have any brilliant suggestions?

Comment: Did you have a look at the "media9" package? The documentation also contains some examples on how to embed videos.